# How can i enable debug in android project properties (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I am developing an app in Xamarin Android and I keep getting this warning in Visual Studio:

> Android Application is running (debug is disabled in android project
>   properties)

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW46h.png)

How can i enable debug in android project properties?? I have added in AssemblyInfo.cs the following code as mentioned somewhere.

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

But nothing changes and no breakpoints are being hit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few things you need to look at.

1) One way to double check that it is at the project level would be looking at the csproj file for the project using notepad++ or some other text editor and looking at the debugtype, debugger, debug symbols for the property group Debug|X

[image]

2) Make sure the setting inside the project properties that enable developer instrumentation is checked.. may be a little different in Xamarin Studio or an iOS project

[image]

3) If those simple properties are all set properly you may have a bigger issue related to mbd files not getting properly updated. Some people have had success clearing their debug folder and obj folders within the project so that the mbd files get rebuilt.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40832/breakpoints-not-being-hit-for-android-and-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 8):

i had the same problem. Then I :

1. Clean the project. Also delete **obj** and **res** folder, in your
   project directory, to be sure.
2. Run it in *debug* mode instead of *release* mode - refer to image below. after changing to *debug* mode press F5.

[image: Run in Debug Mode]

Answer (score 7):

In my case, finally restart of Visual Studio helped (maybe due to a VS/Xamarin bug). (Project was configured properly.)

Answer (score 6):

I had to turn **Optimize Code** option `OFF` which I had turned ON by mistake I think.
After that delete bin and obj folders and rebuilding did the work.

Answer (score 3):

In my case -> build -> Configuration Manager -> change de relea

Comment: Weird, this finally did it for me, but I suspect it was a combination of the other answers above also!