CollectionView GC runs many times, MAUI android
I have CollectionView:
<CollectionView 
            x:Name="ItemsList"
            x:DataType="viewModel:ItemsVM"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsCollectionVisible}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Grey}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedTileCommand}"
            SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout 
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalItemSpacing="20"
                HorizontalItemSpacing="20"
                Span="2" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Item">
            <Grid Padding="2">
                <custom:ItemTile
                ItemModel="{Binding .}"
            />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

And ItemTile:
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Grid 
                Background="{StaticResource White}" 
                WidthRequest="322" HeightRequest="86" 
                RowDefinitions="0.95*, *"
                ColumnDefinitions="13, *"
                >

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" ColumnDefinitions="*, 84">
                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.Name}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleBlue}" />
                    <Polygon Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.IssueTypes, Converter={StaticResource IssueTypeToColorConverter}}" Points="0,0 84,0 84,41 43,41" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.IssueTypes, Converter={StaticResource IssueTypeToIconConverter}}" HeightRequest="35" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid 
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"
                    ColumnDefinitions="63, 31, 57, 31, 69"      
                >
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="7" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" Source="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.Connected, Converter={StaticResource IconConnectionConverter}}"/>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBlue1}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                            <Label.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.Connected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate CON}" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.Connected}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate DISCON}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Label.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="7" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.On, Converter={StaticResource IconStateConverter}}"/>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBlue1}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                            <Label.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.On}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate ON}" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.On}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate OFF}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Label.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="7" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.OperationMode, Converter={StaticResource IconOperatingModeConverter}}"/>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource TextBlue}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                            <Label.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.OperationMode}" Value="{x:Static features:OperationMode.Automatic}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate AUTO}" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.OperationMode}" Value="{x:Static features:OperationMode.Manual}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{local:Translate MAN}" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.OperationMode}" Value="{x:Static features:OperationMode.Undefined}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemModel.OperationMode}" Value="{x:Static features:OperationMode.Setup}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Label.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.ControlTemplate>

And I create/update item in my collectionView like:
if (Items.Count != receivedData.Count)
{
    Items.Clear();
    Items.AddRange(receivedData);
}
var differentElements = receivedData.Except(Items).ToList();

foreach (var element in differentElements)
{
    var existingElement = Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == element.Name);
    int index = Items.IndexOf(existingElement!);
    Items[index].On = element.On;
    Items[index].Connected = element.Connected;
    Items[index].IssueTypes = element.IssueTypes;
    Items[index].OperationMode = element.OperationMode;
}

And everytime when CollectionView is created the GC runs and is slowing down loading data.
App received data immediately because I get data from UdpClient but loading and showing in UI take a while. Below there are logs from output when the CollectionView is created. The amount of GC runs is related with how many items are in CollectionView. I spotted this issue in Android Emulator but when I run app from release apk file the loading take a while as well, but it a little bit faster then in the debug mode.
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3186(451KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5741KB/11MB, paused 963us,128us total 22.669ms
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=8.24ms min=2.93ms max=31.73ms count=35
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 1627(88KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5780KB/11MB, paused 814us,100us total 19.915ms
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 388(67KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5809KB/11MB, paused 616us,94us total 18.880ms
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=6.99ms min=3.35ms max=27.69ms count=31
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 704(62KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5874KB/11MB, paused 1.196ms,91us total 17.312ms
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 420(57KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5912KB/11MB, paused 914us,91us total 18.945ms
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=7.25ms min=3.05ms max=25.70ms count=30
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 361(50KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5942KB/11MB, paused 612us,102us total 20.923ms
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=5.72ms min=2.97ms max=26.90ms count=30
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 726(76KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 6009KB/11MB, paused 1.836ms,98us total 28.911ms
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 416(59KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 6045KB/11MB, paused 1.799ms,94us total 21.606ms
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=10.53ms min=2.91ms max=34.14ms count=36
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 699(60KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 6113KB/11MB, paused 591us,119us total 21.916ms
[mobileapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 361(66KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 6142KB/11MB, paused 579us,114us total 28.567ms


What's the actual problem? Do you mean the data is loading too slowly at the initialization time?

Yes, exactly, the problem is the long display time of the ItemTile in the CollectionView. It receives the data immediately, but I have to wait 2-3 seconds for the data to be displayed in the CollectionView. If there are 3-4 items in the list, it takes about 1-2 seconds, but if there are about 20 items, it takes ~ 4 seconds.

Should I treat this as a problem or a serious issue? Is this typical behaviour?

I am guessing you have an ObservableCollection implementation? You, possibly have an order N^2 complexity foreach loop because of the IndexOf call inside the loop. A lot of things could be happening that can describe the slow down. Some explorative testing and or narrowing down of the problem is required before you can truly determine if the GC is a symptom versus the cause.

@StephenQuan I am using ObservableRangeCollection from Refractored.MvvmHelpers. I've tested it without foreach, only adding elements to collection or create new ObservableRangeCollection and the result was the same.

Have you tried simplifying the layout? Nesting Grids is not great for performance.

Second, in the foreach loop, dereference the Items[index] each time is wasteful.  You may try something like,
var item = Items[index];
Item.On = element.On;

When I unchecked developer instrumentation in debugging options for debug profile the app runs faster, accetable for me. I follow the best answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336740/how-can-i-enable-debug-in-android-project-properties-xamarin-android

So the GC is not the problem. I  think you may simplify the UI or test the performance on an android device.

Since you use a fixed HeightRequest and WidthRequest for the parent Grid in the item template you can set ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" to the collectionview. Hope this helps.
